# Operation System not found during USB boot

Tags: boot, usb, 14.10

Machine : Dell XPS 15z

OS : Ubuntu 14.10

I want to install wiindows 8 using USB Drive, I have Bootable USB available, and I have selected Boot Priority to USB.

But I am not able to load OS for installation, it says "Operation System Not Found"

Here are screen shots of the BIOS:

[image]  [image][image] [image]

Comment: plug the usb and access bios.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/BTuDt.jpg Expand hard drive in boot options in the screen shot.. make sure usb disk is up in the list in hard disk section too..

Comment: Yes I Have already did that Image is to show BIOS config :)

Comment: I think you want Removable Drive to be the top.